# Probability theory and application

Tags: probability

A recent nationwide poll of $1280$ respondents found that if voters must choose between Coalition and Labor candidates only, $51$% prefer the Coalition candidate. Does this constitute evidence that the Coalition would win an election held today? Answer this question with reference to:

(a) A $95$% confidence interval for the proportion of all voters that prefer the Coalition, and

(b) A hypothesis test at the $0.05$ significance level.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please show your work or indicate what you have tried. This way people can better help you where you are stuck.

Comment: I am not getting how to proceed.

Comment: You start by observing that if $x\%$ of the population prefer the coalition then the result of the survey has a binomial distribution $N_c \sim \mbox{Binomial}(x/100,1280)$ and the corresponding proportion is $N_c/1280$

Answer (score 3):

Let x be the population. Suppose X~Binomial(n,p), then $\hat{p}=\frac{X}{n}$ is an unbiased estimator for p. $E[p]=p$ and $Var[p]=\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$

Since $np>5$ and $n(1-p)>5$, by Central Limit Theorem, we can assume that $\hat{p}$ is approximately normal.

So, $\frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}}$ ~ N(0,1)

$P(a<\frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}}<b)=95\%$, where a would be the 2.5% quantile and b be the 97.5% quantile of a standard normal distribution.

After calculation by R studio, we have $a=-1.96, b=1.96$

So the 95% confidence interval would be

$[\hat{p}+a\times\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}},\hat{p}+b\times\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}]$

$\Rightarrow [0.5-1.96\sqrt{\frac{0.51\times 0.49}{1280}}+0.5+1.96\sqrt{\frac{0.51\times 0.49}{1280}}]$

$\Rightarrow [0.473,0.527]$

Since $p<0.5$ falls in that confidence interval, there's no significant evidence showing that Coalition candidate would win.

An hypothesis test would be:

$H_0: p=0.5$ vs $H_1:p>0.5$

Let the test statistic be $T=\frac{\hat{p}-p}{\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}}=\frac{0.51-0.5}{\sqrt{\frac{0.51\times 0.49}{1280}}}=0.716$

Calculating p-value: $P(T>0.716|p=0.5)=0.237$

Since $\alpha=0.05<0.237$, we would fail to reject $H_0$. That is to say, no significant evidence shows that Coalition candidate would win.